# Why isn't there a definite article in front of "savior of the movies"?

Tags: definite-article

The following is taken from a CNN article. Why doesn't the boldfaced phrase have a definite article?

> Dubbed **savior of the movies** by Steven Spielberg himself, Cruise concluded his speech on Sunday by saying, “See you at the movies.”

[Tom Cruise pilots ‘Top Gun: Maverick’ plane during MTV Movie & TV Awards acceptance speech](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/05/07/entertainment/tom-cruise-pilots-top-gun-plane-mtv/index.html)

Comment: The linked question doesn't mention this specific wording but the same principle applies here.

Comment: @Laurel The question then is whether "savior of the movies" is considered a specific role like "sales manager."